# Does SQLITE3 support Virtual Tables on Windows Phone?

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, windows-phone-7

I have create an SQLite3 database using SQLite3 Management Studio for use in a **Windows Phone project**. Database contains normal tables and one **virtual table FTS4** populated with a large amount of data. I am using also VICI project libraries in order to access the database. When I execute a normal SQL query like the following **everything is OK**:

```
var filtered = CSDatabase.RunQuery<IndexCodes>(@"select * from V_CM_ORDER_Normal where Description Like '%" + strToFind + "%'");
```

...But if I execute a query against the **virtual table** like the following a **null reference exception is throwned**:

```
var filtered = CSDatabase.RunQuery<IndexCodes>(@"select * from V_CM_ORDER_Virtual where Description MATCH '*" + strToFind + "*'");
```

IndexCodes is a simple class:

```
public class IndexCodes
{
     public int int1 { get; set; }
     public string str2 { get; set; }
     public string str3 { get; set; }
     public int int4 { get; set; }
}
```

I cannot solve the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Unfortunately after further research I found that current free libraries for Sqlite3 they do not support FTS on Windows Phone. This is sad ....

Comment: are you able to pull the source and compile with the `SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3` compiler directive stated http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_2? I'm curious as I need a sqlite solution with FTS

Comment: No the dll for WP 7.5 is written in C#

Comment: Understand, but I'm wondering if this project has the same issue for enabling FTS as the original project. I'll continue to poke around. If anything changes, please post an update here.